# Is it possible to convert CAD file to CAM file or CAM file to CAD file?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

By using Autodesk Platform Service, is it possible to convert CAD file to CAM file or CAM file to CAD file?

Comment: Current translation of Model Derivative API of APS does not support to convert CAD to CAM, or CAM to CAD. It only provides the geometries data and properties of the CAD file. you may have to take advantage of Autodesk Inventor CAM or Fusion 360 CAM